# GSON - json to generic object

Tags: json, serialization, gson

I have a use case where an API will get a generic collection of Key|Value pairs in json. There are no defined attributes in the input json. I need to map it to a generic object and process the data..

JSON input:

```
"[{ "PostalCode": "345", "Region": "MA", "Enabled": "True" },
  {"PostalCode": "989", "Country": "US", "Enabled": "True" }
]";
```

I am using GSON to deserialize this to java object. On mapping this to a generic object like:

```
Object obj = new GsonBuilder().create()
                              .fromJson(jsonInput, Object.class);
```

i get a an object of Array list of HashMaps (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap).

From here how do i get individual key and values like `key = PostalCode` & `value = 345`?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Also study https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already got an array list of com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap, Now you need to iterate this list to get each key value pair :

```
Object obj = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonInput, Object.class);

        List<LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object>> jsonMapList = (List<LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object>>) obj;

        for (LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object> jsonMap : jsonMapList) {

            Set<Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet = jsonMap.entrySet();

            for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : entrySet) {

                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. I have tested it.
import this

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

Type type = new TypeToken<List<LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object>>>(){}.getType();
List<Map<Object, Object>> treeMap = newGsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonInput,type);
```